# PowerShell uses the short 8.3 form for env:Temp

Tags: windows, powershell, environment-variables

Please help me to deal with PowerShell environment variable.

I had learned that PowerShell has special syntax to access the system environment variable values. So I've tried to execute:

```
$env:Temp
```

in the PowerShell 6.2.4 console on Windows 10. The output is strange:

```
C:\Users\OD42B~1.BOR\AppData\Local\Temp
```

It has my Windows user name shortened to the 8.3 form.
The problem is that I can't use the `cd $env:temp` command, it displays the following error:

```
cd : An object at the specified path C:\Users\OD42B~1.BOR does not exist.
```

But I can do `cd %temp%` in the `cmd` terminal.

I've tried Windows PowerShell app (`%SystemRoot%\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe`) but `cd $env:Temp` does not works either.

I've checked environment variable configuration option (Sytem properties\Environment variables) and both `TEMP` and `TMP` variables are shown using the long form profile folder name, like `c:\users\o.borolongprofilename\AppData\Local\Temp`.

How can I make `cd $env:Temp` work for a non-8.3 profile name in the PowerShell?

#### UPD

- PowerShell `get-childitem env:Temp` output is `C:\Users\OD42B~1.BOR\AppData\Local\Temp`.
- Cmd `echo %temp%` output is the same `C:\Users\OD42B~1.BOR\AppData\Local\Temp` (but `cd %temp%` works in the cmd).
- `TEMP` environment variable in the UI is set properly (value shown is like `c:\users\o.borolongprofilename\AppData\Local\Temp`).

  However `TEMP` value is shown like `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Temp` when I try to edit `TEMP` using the UI.
- PowerShell `get-childitem env:userprofile` displays full name like `c:\users\o.borolongprofilename` (surprise).

#### UPD2

I've just checked PowerShell 7 rc2 but the result is the same: `cd $env:Temp` does not work.

#### UPD3

Thank you for helping me.
I've [found the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10782739/how-to-change-to-temp-directory-in-powershell/10787325#10787325) provided by the @Smock comment link:

`cd (gi $env:temp).fullname`

Comment: What value does `get-childitem env:Temp` return ? Also check the environment variables set via the gui interface - is it 8.3 there? What does `echo %Temp%` from cmd prompt give you?

Comment: @Smock thanks for helping me. Please find question updated with answers you have requested.

Comment: Perhaps [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10787325/2061716) will provide a solution (if not a fix)? `cd (gi $env:temp).fullname`

Comment: `cd "$env:temp"`

Comment: @Bill_Stewart it does not work in PowerShell pscore6. The same as in 7-rc2 preview

Comment: When you say that it didn't work, you have to say _how_ it didn't work.

Comment: What is the returned value for `[Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable("Temp")` ?

Comment: @Bill_Stewart it fails exactly the same as before `cd : An object at the specified path C:\Users\OD42B~1.BOR does not exist.`, nothing new. Does it work on your side (with non 8.3 profile name)? Actually I've found the solution already (using the @Smock comment)

Comment: @Theo `[Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable("Temp")` powershell output is `C:\Users\OD42B~1.BOR\AppData\Local\Temp`

Comment: Ok, then try to find if your Temp variable is not defined multiple times. There are three 'targets' for the environment vars: `Machine`, `User` and `Process`. Try ou these commands: `[Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable("Temp", [EnvironmentVariableTarget]::Machine)`, `[Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable("Temp", [EnvironmentVariableTarget]::User)`, `[Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable("Temp", [EnvironmentVariableTarget]::Process)` to see the different values returned

Comment: @Theo `[Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable("Temp", [EnvironmentVariableTarget]::User)` produces the correct output like `C:\Users\o.borolongprofilename\AppData\Local\Temp`.

Comment: ..and the other commands? (Process in particular)?

Comment: @Theo `Machine` prints `c:\windows\temp` and `Process` outputs `C:\Users\OD42B~1.BOR\AppData\Local\Temp`. I've found the answer from @Smock comment thank you. But it is not possible to mark the question as duplicate since the answer is on stackoverflow site.

Comment: Seems that it has a problem with 8.3 file names (hence why the expanded filename works). When you are in `cmd`, you can use `dir /x` to display the 8.3 filenames for files. Determine a short filename and see if PS works with it (`gc`, etc.).

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for helping me. I've found [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10782739/how-to-change-to-temp-directory-in-powershell/10787325#10787325) provided by the @Smock comment link:

`cd (gi $env:temp).fullname`

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what causes this, but you could add a small piece of powershell in your profile:

```
$env:TEMP = [Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable("Temp", [EnvironmentVariableTarget]::User)
```

That way, `$env:Temp` will be updated each time you launch PowerShell

Answer (score 0):

You can also get the path from registry value and use it:

But not using this one: **`HKCU\Environment`**

```ps1
[HKCU:\Environment]
@TEMP=%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Temp
TEMP    REG_EXPAND_SZ    %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Temp
```

---

> The output also came with:  **`%USERPROFILE%`**, so....

---

---

...try using this registry key: **`HKCU\Environment`**

```ps1
[HKCU:\Volatile Environment]
@LOCALAPPDATA=C:\Users\ecker\AppData\Local
LOCALAPPDATA    REG_SZ    C:\Users\ecker\AppData\Local
```

---

And concatenate only the output sequence with:**`TEMP`** `==>` **`"$path_str\TEMP"`**

---

```ps1
$path_str = (Get-ItemProperty "HKCU:\Volatile Environment")|Select-Object -ExpandProperty LOCALAPPDATA | Resolve-path ; cd "$path_str\TEMP"

# Or using aliases #

$path_str = (gp "HKCU:\Volatile Environment")|select -ExpandProperty LOCALAPPDATA | rvpa ; cd "$path_str\TEMP"
```

---